# Making a reference to a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I have the tag for a custom UITableViewCell but I am not sure how I should reference it?

What is the standard approach here.

I thought something close to this but of course this will not work right?:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[self.mainTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:tag inSection:0]];
```

I make this reference when a button is pressed in the custom implementation of that cell using a delegate method to pass it to my view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not refer to cell itself, because is just interface to show your data. Cells can be (and should be) reused and filled with different data.

Better is store data id, or at lest index of element that cell.

Read more in docs [A Closer Look at Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Comment: from where you need reference to cell ?

Comment: If you have a button on custom cell just set indexPath.row to button.tag and in button action you can get data from datastore by this index

Answer (score 0):

To get from a button in a cell to the cell itself, walk up the view hierarchy:

```
UIView* v = sender; // sender is the button that was tapped
do {
    v = v.superview;
} while (![v isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]);
DiscoverCell* cell = (DiscoverCell*)v;
```